# Bypassing base class constructor calling

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am writing some classes which use types and functions from another library.  This library requires initialization before calling any other function.  Further, the classes use data types provided by the library which must also be initialized before use (but after the library is initialized).  The classes look like the following:

```
class A {
 public:
  A() { init(); }
  void init() { lib_type_init(&t); }
  // ...
  // Other methods
  // ...
 protected:
  lib_type t;
  // ...
  // Other fields
  // ...
}
```

I don't want to have to explicitly call `init()` on instances of `A`, because I have a lot of instances of `A` in my application, so I call `init()` in the constructor.  However, this presents a problem when I want to define an instance of `A` at the global scope.  So I figured inheritance was the correct answer, simply providing a constructor which doesn't call `init()` and requiring the application to explicitly call `init()` before use in a global instance.  For example:

```
class global_A : public A {
 public:
  global_A() {}
}
```

However, this is still an issue, because in C++, base class constructors are called by derived classes if the constructor has no arguments.  This obviously causes issues at runtime when global constructors of objects are called (it tries to call the library init function and produces an error because the library itself isn't initialized).

These classes have a relatively large number of methods and I don't want my code to blow up in size. With this being said, is there a better approach to solving this other than completely copying `A` to `global_A` sans the constructor?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I don't quite understand how your suggestion solves anything.  I have a lot of global and local instances of `A` (used in many diff functions). I don't want to have to call `init()` on all local instances because it pollutes my code.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Every single instance of `A` must call `init()`.  It is to initialize the internal data type as per the specifications of the external library.

Comment: I don't completely understand the question. Your local instances need to call `init()`, and there is some kind of separate `init()` that should only be run once before any global instances are constructed?

Comment: @AndyG It's a threading library which must be initialized itself (i.e. `lib_init(&argc, &argv)` in `main`).  Then, every use of `lib_type` must be initialized (i.e. `lib_type_init(&t)` where t is of type `lib_type`). Does this clear things up? I'm only concerned with the calls to `lib_type_init()` as the need to be called in my class.

Comment: It sounds like `A` should inherit from `Global_A` not the other way around.

Comment: @ChrisDrew Actually that is a very good point... I should have `A` inherit from `global_A` and call `init()` in it's constructor.  I tested this and it seems to work just fine.  If you post an answer with this solution, I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like `A` should inherit from `global_A`, not the other way around.

Although, you might want to think up a better name than `global_A`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the default constructor always calls `init()` automatically. To have a public `init()` function only makes sense if there are other constructors which don't call `init()`. You should just call the corresponding constructor from the member initializer list of the derived class:

```
global_A::global_A(): A(some_arguments) {}
```

An alternative approach could be the use of a function local object to which a reference is returned and calling this function at an opportune time after the library is initialized:

```
global_A& global() {
    static global_A rc;
    return rc;
}
```

Other than that, not that you are probably best off **not* having any global objects in the first place! In general any global state makes code hard to test and causes problem when concurrency is involved.

Answer (score 1):

Create a non-default constructor on your base class that does not call init().  Explicitly call this non-default constructor in the initialization list of the constructor for your global class.